# SQL Server Agent 2012 not executing SSIS 2012 package that connects to Oracle but runs OK from SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, authentication, ssis

I've been fighting this for a while now, and tried many things, I am finally overwhelmed.

I had many SSIS packages in SQL Server 2008 working perfectly, bringing data from SQL, MySQL and Oracle. Then I decided to upgrade to SQL 2012 and the packages won't run. I created them all again using VS2010 and they run great from SSIS, but the ones that connect to Oracle do not work. After several errors, I got this:

> Executed as user: Domain\UserName. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  12:00:00 PM  Error: 2014-03-01 12:00:04.25     Code: 0xC0208449     Source: SalesBacklog ADO NET Source [2]     Description: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection {01F532A5-4542-4833-9103-5FCAEC4EA4A2} with the following error message: "Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.".  End Error  Error: 2014-03-01 12:00:04.25     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: SalesBacklog SSIS.Pipeline     Description: ADO NET Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC0208449.  End Error  Error: 2014-03-01 12:00:04.25     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: SalesBacklog SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2014-03-01 12:00:04.25     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: SalesBacklog      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  12:00:00 PM  Finished: 12:00:04 PM  Elapsed:  3.297 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

My new server specs are:

- Platform: NT64
- System: Xeon L5520 2.27GHz (16 proc), 66.1GB RAM
- OS: Windows Server 2012
- DB: SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100

I've installed, uninstalled, over and over, in different order, the Oracle 32 and 64 Clients. But no luck.

Lately I strongly believe that my problem might be related to permissions of the SQL Agent to run the package and not a problem with the Oracle Clients. I tried all types of authentications (which are quite confusing at times) and I get another wide arrange of errors.

Is anyone out there with any idea of how should I go about it? I am starting from scratch and I will try every step, all over again. If I find the issue, I'll keep you posted.

Thank you!

Comment: Not to be silly, but are you running the packages in 32 bit when you encounter the error?

Comment: It might sounds silly, but there are so many programs and services running that is hard to tell. OS is 64bit, SQL server is 64bit, and I have both 32bit and 64bit Oracle Client versions installed on the machine. Now, in my defense, it has been like that for months, and it work if I run it manually. I'll try to download the latest 64bit version from Oracle and I'll keep you posted. Thanks for the response!

Comment: When you create your job, in the job step's advanced tab, there's a check box for 32bit mode. Was that checked or not?

Comment: I have to admit that this is the first time I see this checkbox. Let me install the Oracle Client again a give it shot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After much effort, @billinkc told me all I needed to know: check box for 32bit mode

1. Open the SQL Agent Job
2. On the "Steps" section, select the step that executes the SSIS Package that connects to Oracle
3. Under the "Execution options" tab, check the check box "Use 32bit runtime"

This time though I made sure to [deinstall all Oracle Clients](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B10131_02/deinstall.htm) and just install the 32bit Oracle Client.